# AngularJS DatePicker with timezone selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Is there any way to edit timezone of input[type="date"] in agularJS from some kind of datepicker?

Comment: Take a look https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. It has Datepicker with `ng-model-options` and `timezone` in it

Comment: I've tried `ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}"` and created a second input with type="text" to monitor model value and still receiving date with my local timezone in it

Answer (score 0):

Timezone can do with the help of http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```js
angular.module('demo', ['angularMoment'])
  .controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.inputDate = new Date();
    $scope.inputDateUtc = moment($scope.inputDate).utc().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    $scope.inputDateNoUtc = moment($scope.inputDate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    $scope.dateChanged = function(argument) {
      $scope.inputDateUtc = moment($scope.inputDate).utc().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
      $scope.inputDateNoUtc = moment($scope.inputDate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/0.10.3/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl" class="container">
  <h4>input date</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="inputDate" ng-change="dateChanged()" ng-Trim="false" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <pre>Date with UTC: <em>{{inputDateUtc}}</em></pre> 
  <hr>
  <pre>Date without UTC: <em>{{inputDateNoUtc}}</em></pre>

</div>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2yw0NIe1oc0AxUnOw3Zg